# Unable to capture data from React MUI JOY UI <Select/> component via React-Hook-Form

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-hook-form

I'm building a form and I'm using Mui's Joy UI's Select Component, via React hook form,
I am unable to capture the data when I choose an Option from the Select.
It just shows as null

`

```
              <Controller
                  name="category"
                  control={control}
                  
                  rules={{ required: 'Category is required' }}
                  render={({ field: { onChange, field} }) => (
                    <>
                    <Tooltip
                      title="Choose a category to help people find you " 
                      placement="left"
                      arrow
                      color="info"
                      size="sm"
                      variant="outlined"
                    >
                      <Select
                        {...field}
                        onChange={onChange}
                        defaultValue="wew"
                        variant="soft"
                        fullWidth
                        
                        error={Boolean(errors.category)}
                        
                      >
                        <Option value="wew">wew</Option>
                        <Option value="lol">lol</Option>
                      </Select>
                    </Tooltip>
                    </>
                  )}
                />`
```

I've tried using the Controller component from react hook form but it still does not work

putting an onChange finally changes the UI when I select an option but the formState isn't updated. It still shows up as null

Comment: Could you add a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Answer (score 0):

Need to implement onChange funciton by using useState hook to store the value in a variable

const [v, setV] = useState("")
...
onChange={(e)=>setV(e.target.value)}

Comment: Please use proper Markdown formatting to clearly separate explanations from code in your answer. See the Stack Overflow Help page: [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Answer (score 0):

```
                    <Select
                        multiple
                        {...field}
                        onChange={(_, newValue) => {
                            setValue('categories', newValue);
                        }}>
                        ...
                    </Select>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).